# if the runner advancing to second base is hit by the throw from the outfield, is he out?

Tags: baseball

If the runner advancing from first to second is hit by the ball thrown by the outfielder while not on the bag, is he out?

Answer (score 4):

If the runner is determined to have "intentionally interfered" with the throw, then yes, the runner is out. This is covered under Rules 5.09(b)(3) and 6.01(a)(10) in the [2016 MLB Rule Book](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2016/official_baseball_rules.pdf).

> Any runner is out when:
>
> - He intentionally interferes with a thrown ball
>
> It is interference by a batter or a runner when:
>
> - He ... intentionally interferes with a thrown ball ... The umpire shall call the runner out in accordance
>   with Rule 5.09(b)(3) (former Rule 7.08(b)).

---

If the runner is determined to have not intentionally interfered with the throw, then the runner is not out<sub>[(1)](http://baseball-rules.com/FAQs.htm)</sub>. Moreover, the ball is still live<sub>[(2)](http://umpirebible.com/rules/runnerHit.htm#thrown)</sub>.

Comment: @Joe I didn't update the answer at the time because I didn't find an "official" source to back up the claim that being hit by a thrown ball was not an out unless in the case of intentional interference. Thus, I only listed the definitive case in which the runner becomes out.